# Python .month format is numeric(1) want MMM(Jan)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column to retrieve only month stat from `Trade Trade Dt` column.

I want format MMM below to be a number.

```
map_cat['Trade Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(map_cat['Trade Trade Dt']).month
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on how to ask a good question may also be useful.

Comment: Try [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strftime` with %b

```
map_cat['Trade Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(map_cat['Trde Trade Dt']).strftime('%b')
```

Comment: Do you not need `.dt.strftime`?

Comment: @Dan this is `DatetimeIndex`, so you access time like method directly. You need `.dt` for normal series.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
map_cat['Trade Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(map_cat['Trde Trade Dt']).month_name().str[:3]
```